# Get value from JtextField to another class

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Im trying to get jTextField value in another class but always get error null exception. Here is my code :

Class Main :

```
public class FormTambahDoc extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Utility utility;

    public FormTambahDoc() {
        initComponents();
        utility = new Utility();
        setButton();
    }

    public  String gettextIdentitasPengguna() {
        return textIdentitasPengguna.getText();
    }

     private void setButton() {
        btnSimpan.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { utility.cek();} });
    }

  }
```

Class another:

```
public class Utility {

FormTambahDoc formTambahDoc;
//FileJpaController controller;


public  void cek()
{

   String inputText = formTambahDoc.gettextIdentitasPengguna();
   System.out.println(inputText);
   //return `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`


}

}
```

What's wrong in this code ?

Comment: Have you intialized your variable `formTambahDoc`? Change the third line to `FormTambahDoc formTambahDoc = new FormTambahDoc();`

Comment: im already try it but when im changing textIdentitasPengguna value on the GUI the output is still the default value so that not what i expected

Comment: Can you add some more code. From the code snippet it is not clear what is relation between 2 classes.

Comment: this is the complete code hope u can help @AntonK. 
http://pastebin.com/UkvVSTpK

Comment: when the code is running the compiler become hang, the error is something like stackoverflow. sorry that what i got, i forget to copy that error here @SergiyMedvynskyy

Answer (score 1):

You should create instance of `FormTambahDoc` before you ca use it:
`FormTambahDoc formTambahDoc = new FormTambahDoc();` or get the instance from somewhere. Otherwise formTambahDoc will always be null. Check again your AWT tutorial.

Comment: im already try it but when im changing  _textIdentitasPengguna_  value on the GUI the output is still the default value

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
public class FormTambahDoc extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Utility utility;

    public FormTambahDoc() {
        initComponents();
        utility = new Utility(this);
        setButton();
    }

    public  String gettextIdentitasPengguna() {
        return textIdentitasPengguna.getText();
    }

     private void setButton() {
        btnSimpan.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { utility.cek();} });
    }

}

public class Utility {

    FormTambahDoc formTambahDoc;
    //FileJpaController controller;
    public Utility(FormTambahDoc aForm) {
        formTambahDoc = aForm;
    }

    public  void cek()
    {

       String inputText = formTambahDoc.gettextIdentitasPengguna();
       System.out.println(inputText);
       //return `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`


    }

}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - constructor Utility in class sharesystem.digital_file.controller.Utility cannot be applied to given types;
  required: sharesystem.digital_file.view.FormTambahDoc
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length